# Want paging in MVC Webgrid on both top and bottom

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paging, webgrid

I Want paging in `MVC Webgrid` on both top and bottom. 
I did it using `Grid.Pager()` but now the action is getting called twice when i click either top of the page or bottom.

Comment: Code?
View?
Bueller?

Comment: @{
            WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.Items, canSort: true, rowsPerPage: Model.Paging.CurrentPageSize, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "container-grid", ajaxUpdateCallback: "webGridCallBack");
            
            grid.PageIndex = ((Model.Items.Count / Model.Paging.CurrentPageSize) >= Model.Paging.CurrentPage) ? Model.Paging.CurrentPage : 0;
                }
                @grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All, "<<", "<", ">", ">>")

Comment: @grid.GetHtml(
     tableStyle: "mi-data-table align-center js-mi-data-table mi-data-table--selectable",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "checkableGrid" },
    alternatingRowStyle: "info",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns: grid.Columns(girdi.Column(columnName: "a"))

Comment: please edit your question with your code, don't just add comments